# Ruby gem to "lock" an accepted agreement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timestamp

I am looking for a Ruby gem to lock an agreement digitally. In other words, when a user clicks "I have read and accept the agreement", I would like to be able to save a copy of the agreement right at the time the user accepted and be able to later on prove that that was indeed a copy of the agreement at that time (in other words make it tamper proof).

Comment: This Q is off topic in multiple ways. It asks for an external resource, there is no indication of what you have tried, it is vague and difficult to tell what you are asking. What would constitute "proof"? You may need specialist legal advice, not software advice.

Comment: @NeilSlater I am essentially asking for a gem that can mark a document with an encrypted timestamp. This is a technical issue, not a legal one.

Comment: If that's really all you need (it is not clear), then you could ask at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ where such a thing would be on topic. But such a signature would not be "proof" of anything, just a record for your and the user's reference. For instance, if the record was contended ("I didn't agree the *that*!") what would you do to prove that they did? If the data is stored on your server, there isn't a cryptographic system that can prove that the user clicked a button for the document.

Comment: . . . or more accurately there is not a clever algorithm that secures such an agreement in isolation. If you are concerned that an end user might say they did not agree to something, you would need verification from a third party. Log files from ISPs, document escrow, record of payment, an *actual* legal contract etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not possible. If you are able to create this prove yourself then you are also able to recreate that proof with a different content or any timestamp.

But there are services that add digital signatures to your document. If both sides (or a court) also trusts this service provider then this might be a way: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature

The basic idea is: After the user agreed, you send all interesting pieces or information (content of agreement, ip address, timestamp, user address, etc.) to the service. The services returns you a signed version of that document. This works as a proof, since you are unable to change that document later on.